# get user id in Django clas based view

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

i'm trying to implement the following class View and populate customer field with a filtered list of customers retrieved from Customers Model but filtered by user id

```
class SellCreateView(CreateView):
model = Sell
fields = [
        'name',
        'store',
        'customer',
    ]
```

in function based view i do something like the following:

```
def sell_create(request):
    customer_list = Customer.objects.filter(belongs_to=request.user.id)
    ...
    form.fields['customer'].queryset = customer_list
```

but i can't make this work in class view! Any idea how should i do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `get_context_data` to filter by user

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#using-class-based-views

Comment: use `self.request.user.id`